# Google Analytics + Wordpress /dir/ and /dir/index.php appearing as separate items

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

The Google Analytics information for one of my Wordpress sites is showing /dir/ and /dir/index.php as separate items - is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the profile settings set the default page to index.php. [Google Analytics Index Page Tracked Separately](https://www.google.com/support/analyticshelp/bin/answer.py?answer=1009675&hl=en_US&utm_id=ad)

> Even though www.example.com/ may be the same page as www.example.com/index.html, they show up as two separate entries in your reports. You can configure Google Analytics to treat them as the same page by defining the Default page for your profile:
>
> - Click the Analytics Settings link.
> - In the Website Profiles list, find the profile to modify and click Edit.
> - Click Edit next to Main Website Profile Information.
> - In the Default page text box, enter the default (or index) page for this domain. This is the page that loads when a visitor enters only the domain of your site into their address bar. For example, if www.example.com loads your index.html web page, enter index.html in this text box.
> - Click Save Changes to update your default page, or Cancel to exit without saving.

Comment: Ah, I see what I've done now. I applied this setting several weeks back but I must be seeing old results for /dir/ and new results for /dir/index.php side by side. Thank you for the prompt!

Comment: Right, GA won't apply changes to historical data.

Comment: Yeah, I wish they would - or a least allow you to trigger a refresh.